Call to undefined relationship on model. on production but not on localhost
I'm working on a laravel 10 project and I have issues on production (local server) but not in localhost (php artisan serve).
I have a livewire component that deals comment submitting on a request.
I have two models (User and Request) linked by a many to many relation with a pivot table (Guests).
There is my Request model:
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Comment;
use App\Models\Project;
use App\Models\Service;
use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\Document;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Request extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

[...]

    public function guests() : BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'guests')->orderBy('name', 'asc');
    }

    public function hasGuest(User $user) : bool
    {
        return $this->guests()->where('user_id', $user->id)->exists();
    }
}


My User mode :
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Role;
use App\Models\Comment;
use App\Models\Service;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use MBarlow\Megaphone\HasMegaphone;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, SoftDeletes, HasMegaphone;

[...]

    public function invitedRequests(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Request::class, 'guests');
    }
}


And my livewire component :
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Models\Comment;
use App\Services\NotificationService;
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Megaphone\NewComment;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CommentInput extends Component
{
    public $req;
    public $comments;
    public $id;
    public $newComment;

    protected $notificationService;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->notificationService = new NotificationService();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.comment-input');
    }

    public function submitComment()
    {
        if($this->newComment)
        {
            try {
                $comm = Comment::create([
                    'content' => $this->newComment,
                    'user_id' => Auth::id(),
                    'request_id' => $this->id,
                ]);

            } catch (\Throwable $th) {
                Log::error($th);
            }
            
            $this->reloadComments();
            $this->newComment = '';

            if($this->req->user_id != Auth::id()) {
                $this->notificationService->sendCommentNotification($this->req->user, $this->req, $comm);

            } elseif($this->req->affected_user_id != Auth::id()) {
                $this->req->affectedUser ? $this->notificationService->sendCommentNotification($this->req->affectedUser, $this->req, $comm) : '';

            } else if($this->req->service->manager_id != Auth::id()) {
                $this->notificationService->sendCommentNotification($this->req->service->manager, $this->req, $comm);
            }

            $guests = $this->req->guests;
            
            foreach($guests as $guest) {

                if ($guest->id != Auth::id() 
                && $guest != $this->req->user 
                && $guest != $this->req->affectedUser
                && $guest != $this->req->service->manager)
                {
                    $this->notificationService->sendCommentNotification($guest, $this->req, $comm);
                }
            }
        }
    }

[...]

}


Only on production it throw me this error :
Call to undefined relationship [guests] on model [App\Models\Request].
I've verified that my migration ran correctly on production server and I have my new guests table with correct foreign keys.

My database has also InnoDB type.
I don't know why it works on localhost but not on my linux server...

Hi some times it will occur because of the type error. I have faced the same issue How I overcome this is to change the App/ to app/ because in some server we need to pass the exact folder name but in local we are not facing this kind of issue.
